# how to manually compile templates twice or more

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, compilation, directive

I want to compile an angular directive first to append attributes and then to compile the code again as other directives. Is there anyway for me to perhaps use compile: pre post or something to compile this

attribute-append 
to
directive 
to
Parent Directive templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let's say you have a directive `<foo></foo>` (`restrict: 'E'`). You want to add attributes dynamically (~ modify the original DOM, not the  template), which should be done in the `$compile` step of the directive. After adding the attributes, to make angularjs realise if there is any new directive that can be triggered, you have to compile the new element. that's what ng-include does, for example. it includes elements in the DOM and compiles them so new directives can be used.

directive `foo`:

```js
compile: function ($tElement, $tAttrs) {
  var el = $tElement[0];
  el.setAttribute('bar', 'newFancyValue');
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
     // you can even append html elements here, for example the template
     element.append("<book></book>");
     $compile(element)(scope);
  };
}
```

and directive `bar` (with `restrict: 'A'`) can have whatever code you want.

This is a related question you might want to read as well [A general directive with a specific type (UI components inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929386/angularjs-complex-directives-for-custom-tags)

look at the transclude function in the docs to see how to add previous inner elements of `foo` in `book`

Comment: what if your 'foo' directive is restrict 'A'? it seems in this case the compile loops forever..

Comment: yeah probably, because after compiling it, angular finds again the attribute that triggered the directive, which makes it compile it again and again. I guess you can remove the attribute in the compile function and return the link function only if the attribute existed. similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929386/a-general-directive-with-a-specific-type-ui-components-inheritance

Comment: Any idea why the first parameter to compile `$tElement` is an array and not an element, thus requiring `var el = $tElement[0];`. Most examples treat it as a single object, but like the OP, I'm getting an array.