# Directive restricting input is not working with type=number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that restricts input to specific symbols, in my case, only numbers. It is made after [filters on ng-model in an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419651/angularjs-filters-on-ng-model-in-an-input/14425022#14425022) and it works fine in text-type inpit.

Directive declared as

```
     .directive('onlydigitinput', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

but in case of numerical input I want to use input type=number, not type=text:

```
<input type="number"  
onlydigitinput="onlydigitinput" required="required" min="1" max="99" maxlength="2">
```

and then it's a problem: I have correct validation based on min-max attribute, but I still can enter all symbols, such as letters, and directive does not work as it should. Additionally, maxlength seems not to have effect. How I can possibly fix my directive to work with type="number" inputs?

Comment: that directive only removes spaces and makes everything lowercase, it does not prevent entering non-number characters.

Comment: @Quad, there is also this expression: .replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');

Comment: oops,did not see it. But as MJV says, it probably because you get a Number as `inputValue` instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, the `maxlength` attribute doesn't work with input type `number`. See e.g.
[maxlength ignored for input type=“number” in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome).

Second, when the input type is `number`, your directive's function only gets a value for the `inputValue` parameter when it's a number. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXU4L/) as an example (the console output might make it clearer).

**Edit:**

How crucial is it for you to use the number type input? If the spinner controls that browsers add to the input field for it aren't a necessity, I'd probably go for a custom type like described here: [How to create a custom input type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736469/how-to-create-a-custom-input-type-in-angular-js)

I've used something very similar for e.g. money input fields (with localized decimal separators etc.).

Comment: Yes, if it is that helpless maybe I have to create a special type.

Comment: and in fact input=text works great with min and max attributes, validating field correctly.

Comment: Yes, and if you have a bunch of those fields and they represent something special, that custom type may also express that well. (E.g. in this case I thought about percentage values, ranging from 1 to 99, and then `<input type="percent" ...>` would be good for readability.)

Comment: You can find the workaround to the problem in following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome/34641129#34641129