# HTML5 email does not allow email with a period

Tags: html

The following email is not accepted with a period, is this a regular expression issue or some bug.

This works

```
abcdefg.jijklmn@abcdedghijklmnopgi.com
```

but the following doesn't (note uppercase letter in the email "A" and "J"), i think that is the problem

```
Abcdefg.Jijklmn@abcdedghijklmnopgi.com
```

Html element

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[![\[][1]][1]a-z]{2,3}$" required="" value=""/>
```

Error below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to split that address into two strings?

Comment: @user154248 Split in 2 strings? can you elaborate

Comment: Never mind, didn't read your code closely enough. You can create your own `input` instead of the classic `email` field. Check it out here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736469/how-to-create-a-custom-input-type)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your regex doens't allow capitals.. simply allow capitals..

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[![\[][1]][1]a-z]{2,3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions for emails can be [very difficult](http://emailregex.com/). However, you don't actually need to use a pattern to validate emails as `type="email"` does that for you. Simply remove the pattern entirely and the clients browser will validate the email for you using their in-built regex

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="true" value=""/>
```

I can't actually seem to get email validation to work with the `pattern` attribute at all, as I think it's competing with `type="email"`.