# Custom input types in angular (7)?

Tags: html, angular, input

I'm wondering if it is possible to create custom input types other than the native ones that are listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

If it's possible, how? I'm thinking of a directive which preserves the native input types but extends it with new, custom ones with custom functionality.

e.g. I want to have a IBAN input type, that has a input mask & validation given because of the directive:

```
<input type="iban" [(ngModel)]="iban" />
```

Hope someone can help me out with that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom input type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736469/how-to-create-a-custom-input-type)

Comment: not a duplicate of above - different frameworks

Comment: That duplicate question is for AngularJS (1.x). You wouldn't actually make a new type for input, those are effectively controlled by the browser(s). Instead you would use an existing type, such as `text` and wrap a component around it. You would connect this component as a "custom control" that then can be used with reactive and/or template driven forms. This is effectively how frameworks such as material make custom inputs. There are **many** examples of creating custom input control components, such as https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I think what you are actually needing is a new component. You would not use `input` element directly, that is something the new component would then do within it's template. The caller would then pass an instance of the `IBAN` type (class or interface) to the component.

Comment: you can use a directive `<input iban [(ngModel)]="iban">`. I don't know if work using as selector of the directive some like `selector:"input[type='iban']"`